# How to use a reserved keyword in pydantic model

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I need to create a schema but it has a column called *global*, and when I try to write this, I got an error.

```
class User(BaseModel):

    id:int
    global:bool
```

I try to use another name, but gives another error when try to save in db.

Comment: `global` is a reserved keyword for a reason. Find another name.

Comment: Something like `is_global` would be more clear anyway. Why does it have to be called `global`? Surely there's a way to map python variable names to SQL column names without them needing to be identical.

Comment: Keep in mind that `global` may not be an invalid column name, but it is *syntactically* invalid in a `class` statement like this, so you would need to find another way to add the column to your model.

Comment: As an analogous example, something like `foo.global = 5` would be a syntax error, but `setattr(foo, "global", 5)` is perfectly legal.

Comment: i know that is a reserved keyword man (but i need to use the same name of tables column), because of that i made the question , but the solution given by mx0 work`s fine for me, thank you all guys.

Comment: "Just use another name" is rather obtuse. Sometimes we need to parse data from external sources and APIs (e.g. webhooks sent to us) and we don't have any control over their naming conventions.

Comment: What are the actual errors? Exact error message?

Comment: @Theberzi But external data sources can, or at least _should_, never dictate **how you name your class attributes** (your local variables, effectively). Any data model that requires you to store an arbitrary piece of data under a **specific** arbitrary name is broken, that's an unworkable restriction, because all languages have _some_ syntax rules. Fortunately the pydantic designers provided an out that makes their (still ugly) model _slightly_ less broken, by allowing adjustments to the name mapping via `Config.fields`.

Comment: (And Python has fewer restrictions than most languages, in this regard. Like, it's totally legal to use `property` or `id` or `list` as member names in your class, even though in theory those are all built-in commands or type names. Relatively few of Python's built-in names are restricted from being overridden if you really  _want_ to. The only ones that are totally off limits are the 35 [keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It looks like you are using a *pydantic* module. You can't use the name *global* because it's a reserved keyword so you need to use this trick to convert it.

*pydantic v1*:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    global_: bool

    class Config:
        fields = {
            'global_': 'global'
        }
```

or
*pydantic v1 & v2*:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    global_: bool = Field(..., alias='global')
```

To create a class you have to use a dictionary (because `User(id=1, global=False)` also throws an error):

```
user = User(id=1, global=False)

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> (...)
> File "<input>", line 1
>  User(id=1, global=False)
>             ^^^^^^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

user = User(**{'id': 1, 'global': False})
```

Set `allow_population_by_field_name = True` or `populate_by_name=True`  in config to allow creating models using both `global` and `global_` names (thanks @GooDeeJAY).

*pydantic v1*:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    global_: bool = Field(..., alias='global')

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
```

*pydantic v2*:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    global_: bool = Field(..., alias='global')
    model_config = ConfigDict(populate_by_name=True)


user1 = User(**{'id': 1, 'global': False})
user2 = User(id=1, global_=False)
assert user1 == user2
```

By default schema dump will not use aliased fields:

```
user.dict() # for pydantic v1
user.model_dump() # for pydantic v2
> {'id': 1, 'global_': False}
```

To get data in the correct schema use *by_alias*:

```
user.dict(by_alias=True) # for pydantic v1
user.model_dump(by_alias=True) # for pydantic v2
> {'id': 1, 'global': False}
```

Comment: I wonder, why it's not possible (not working) to use `global_` as parameter name when creating a new class with reserved keywords...

Comment: @machin It is possible by adding `allow_population_by_field_name = True` to `Config` class

Comment: @mX0 could you elaborate on the last point that you mentioned? I did not get why we need "User(**{'id': 1, 'global': False})" or "user.dict(by_alias=True)" after we actually defined our schema using one of the two methods that you explained.

Comment: @sara passing `global` as a named argument is impossible in Python, regardless of what your class definition is.

Comment: @Sara ad1. `global` is a reserved keyword *everywhere*, you can't use it that way. ad2. you need it for dumping schema with the same fields names as was the input